# [Page Object]Parameter for section in nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I have a single-page-app and list of order section within, like this :

```
<form>
   <form-order> // section
     <ElementA>
     <ElementB>
     <ElementC>
   <form-order>
     <ElementA>
     <ElementB>
     <ElementC>
   <form-order>
     <ElementA>
     <ElementB>
     <ElementC>
</form>
```

and in nightwatch page-object :

```
 form-order:{
  selector:'div[class=form-order]',
  elements:{
     ElementA:'#ElementA',
     ElementB:'#ElementB',
     ElementC:'#ElementC',
     }
  }
```

When i call this section, there will be 3 of them,same selector,so the first one will be used.The question is how can i set :nth-child() for this section and elements within,it should be like this:

```
 form-order:{
  selector:"div[class=form-order]:nth-child("+n+")",
  elements:{
     ElementA:"#ElementA",
     ElementB:"#ElementB",
     ElementC:"#ElementC",
     }
  }
```

But i dont know how to do it in nightwach.js or is there any solution for this?
Thank for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can easily define them all together as you are suggesting, but you can define them individually something like this:

```
elements: {
    elementA1 : '.select-content:eq(0) #ElementA',
    elementA2 : '.select-content:eq(1) #ElementA',
    elementC3 : '.select-content:eq(2) #ElementC' //and so on
}
```

This might get you going until you find a better solution. Of course, you should adapt this to the actual HTML you have.

Comment: I have 20 form-orders and 12 elements within, there will be over 200 elements if i follow your solution.Currently, i use command instead of elements,but it is not a good practice.

Comment: yeah, i get it. sorry, don't know how to do that then, will try to check it for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is creating commands, with Nightwatch I create functions that I later call in the "commands" element, for example:

```
var pageFunctions = {
    name_of_function: function(index){
        return this
        .click('xpath', '//*[@id="easycont"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/label['+ index+']/input')
    }
}

module.exports = {
    url: 'url',

    elements:{
        name_of_element:{
        selector: name of any element
        }
    },

    commands: [pageFunctions]
}
```

In the test js:

```
"Name of the test": function(client){
var radio_page = client.page.radioPage()

// and here call my page object function
radio_page.marcarGenero(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently we do this by passing the number of the child as a variable like so -

```
checkDocumentMessages(number, text) {
// Where (number) is the nth-child position of the Message you wish to check
 
 let selector = `.dv-messages-inner > div:nth-child(${number}) .msg-content`;
    
  this.expect.element(selector).text.to.equal(text).before(5000);
     return;
},
```

This then allows us to specify which one we are trying to confirm the text on